# load array value in a variable on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m appending a set of cards with values from the JSON. The cards are being created. but I have different JSONs for each of the cards. The card JSON has more information within it. I want to load the JSON details on click of each card.
I get the list of events from the var `event_data`.
 This JSON creates the cards.

```
function getDashboardData(){
$.ajax({
    url: "API",
    type: "POST",
    data:JSON.stringify({"user_id": userID}),
    //JSON.stringify({"user_id": "user"}),
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function (data) {
        try{
            event_data = data;
            listOfEvents(data.events_list);

        }
        catch(error){
            //console.log(error);
        }

    }

});}
```

In order to create the details for each card I have to post a request by their ids but for now I have hardcoded one id. I have been getting multiple ids and have to load those card details on every card click.

This API gives me more details of the card by posting requests by each id.

```
function getDashboardDataSummary(){

url_data = {"event_id":"bahu4"};
//console.log(url_data);
$.ajax({
    url: "API",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(url_data),
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function (data) {
        eve_2 = data;
    }

})};
```

Comment: What is the question and problem? Where do you call `getDashboardDataSummary()`?

Comment: The question is unclear. We can see that you're likely getting the data correct, so you could easily just take that data and $(someElement).click(function() {oldvar.push(newvar)})

Comment: in the first api call i create the cards from the userID once the user login,i also get the list of events from the first api. from the second api i create the graphs for  each of the card. but i have hardcoded for now. i want to store a each of the card id and create graphs for each card on click .(call the second api on earch card click )

Comment: @thatgibbyguy wanted to make the second api dynamic instead of hard coding the value.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry. i deleted it. i called it in getDashboardData().

Comment: Still going to need to explain in much more detail how this needs to work and where your specific problems are in making it work

Comment: @charlietfl In the first API i get the eventID for creating number of cards. so i create the cards from the first api eg.bahu4 card is created. from the second api i will get the details of each card after i post the eventID. eg.bahu4. when i post bahu4 on the send api i get details of bahu4 card. so the problem is there are many number of cards. im not able to post eventID to the second api one after another. as i have to display details on click of each card.

Comment: absolute no need to use JSON.stringify( for the data property